# Why doesn't Jinja take my JS String variable for what it is?

Tags: jinja2

I have a JavaScript function to make a chart, I must dynamically pass a source of data into it. My sample for this question is 'ice-cream_sales'. The source of data is a String variable.

```
var chosen_data = "ice-cream_sales";

function makeChart(chosen_data){
     var data_source = "{{ url_for('static', filename='data/ {% chosen_data %} .csv')}}";

     d3.select("svg").remove();
     var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
     ...
}

makeChart(chosen_data, "blue", 900, 400); // Make the chart
```

So chosen_data is a string to be concatenated with .csv. It lives in a static folder called data.

If I console.log this string that I'm passing into the function, Jinja turns my JS variable into something wierd which looks like:

`/static/data/Streamchart/%20%7B%25%20chosen_data%20%25%7D%20.csv`

Why does "ice-cream_sales" become "%20%7B%25%20chosen_data%20%25%7D%20" with Jinja, and how can I prevent it?

TYIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a statement like `{% chosen_data %}` inside an expression `{{ }}` because jinja parse it like a simple string which is then escaped as you saw. 
Moreover, `chosen_data` is a javascript variable, not jinja's.

You can find the actual use of Jinja delimiters [here in the docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#synopsis). If you must set the name of your data from javascript, you could use a simple replacing:

```
var data_source = "{{ url_for('static', filename='data/chosen_data.csv')}}";
var data_source = data_source.replace("chosen_data", chosen_data);
```

Otherwise it would be more elegant if you set the variable in Jinja like this:

```
{% set chosen_data = "ice_cream_sales" %}
...
var data_souce = "{{ url_for('static', filename='data/' ~ chosen_data ~ '.csv')}}";
```